# Rest Api for Vtiger Account Creation

Tags: vtiger

Is there any support for creating account / organizations in Vtiger thorugh rest api ? As I have added custom fields to account module. I need to update / create thorough api. please share.

I have tried to create account by inserting entry in database. But it is not good way.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the Example to create contact in vtiger so this will help to you**

```
<?php

function call($url, $params, $type = "GET") {
    $is_post = 0;
    if ($type == "POST") {
        $is_post = 1;
        $post_data = $params;
    } else {
        $url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($params);
    }
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    if (!$ch) {
        die("Cannot allocate a new PHP-CURL handle");
    }
    if ($is_post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $is_post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $return = null;
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        $return = false;
    } else {
        $return = json_decode($data, true);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $return;
}

$endpointUrl = 'http://url/vtigercrm/webservice.php';
$userName = 'admin';
$password = 'admin';
$userAccessKey = 'dsddsdsdsds';

$sessionData = call($endpointUrl, array("operation" => "getchallenge", "username" => $userName));
$challengeToken = $sessionData['result']['token'];
$generatedKey = md5($challengeToken . $userAccessKey);
$dataDetails = call($endpointUrl, array("operation" => "login", "username" => $userName, "accessKey" => $generatedKey), "POST");

$query = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE cf_771='ajay' and cf_781='ajay';";
$queryParam = urldecode($query);

$sessionid = $dataDetails['result']['sessionName'];
$getUserDetail = call($endpointUrl, array("operation" => "query", "sessionName" => $sessionid, 'query' => $query));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($getUserDetail);
echo "</pre>";
if (!empty($getUserDetail['result'])) {
    echo "success!!!!";
} else {
    echo "fail!!!!";
}
```

for mor help visit this link http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html